# MVC - Show list of strings in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Based on this code (auto-generated Control/View code from Visual Studio):

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*Comment: Want to replace EditorFor to DropDownList("Banana, "Apple", "Orange"*@
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add something similar like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

(also auto-generated code, but for `UserId`) instead of `@html.EditorFor...`

I was able to see list of `UserName`(value = `Id`) from db via Controller:

```
ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "UserName", Test.UserId);
```

Now, I don't want that ViewBag read from database, instead I want it to list 3 different strings that I will use to let user to chose for indata(meaning, limit them to choice one of these 3 string instead writing it).

Strings I want it to list:

- "Banana"
- "Apple"
- "Orange"

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDown", new List<SelectListItem>
                                 { new SelectListItem { Text = "Banana", Value = "1", Selected=true},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Apple", Value = "2"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Orange", Value = "3"}
                                   }, "Select Fruit")
```

OR

Get value in model

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, new List<SelectListItem>
                                 { new SelectListItem { Text = "Banana", Value = "1", Selected=true},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Apple", Value = "2"},
                                   new SelectListItem { Text = "Orange", Value = "3"}
                                   }, "Select Fruit")
```

Comment: Thanks it works well! Just a question, is this still a proper way in work area(e.g. average safety) or should I consider other solution?

Comment: @Nyprez Yes, Both are proper way. If you want selected value in your model than use second option otherwise first.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change what you are assigning to `ViewBag.UserId` f.e. like this:

```
var fruits = new List<string> { "Banana", "Apple", "Orange" };
ViewBag.Fruits = fruits.Select(f => new SelectListItem { Text = f, Value = f });
```

Comment: Using `@Html.DropDownList("Fruits", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` in View gave me the error: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Fruits'.`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a second parameter you have to pass the ViewBag.Fruits like this:
`@Html.DropDownList("Fruits", ViewBag.Fruits, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can build your list items:

```
ViewBag.Fruits = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = string.Empty, Value = "-1"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Banana", Value = 0},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Apple", Value = 1},
    }, "Value" , "Text", 1);
```

Comment: Tried to call it in view by: `@Html.DropDownList("Fruits", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })` but I get the error: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Fruits'.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it using enum

```
public enum Fruit { Banana, Apple, Orange }

@Html.DropDownList("FruitSelection", 
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fruit))),
                    "Select Fruit",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Do I add `public enum Fruit` in controller? If I do so, I get the error "Cant resolve symbol 'Fruit'" and for the other 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

MVC Controler

```
  ViewBag.PageSort = new List <SelectListItem> ()
         {
             new SelectListItem () {Value = "1", Text = "Discounts"},
             new SelectListItem () {Value = "2", Text = "New Items"},
             new SelectListItem () {Value = "3", Text = "Lowest Price"},
             new SelectListItem () {Value = "4", Text = "Highest Price"}
         };
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownList("PageSort", ViewBag.PageSortas SelectList, "- Select Sort -", new { @id = "SortID", @name = "SortID", @class = "form-control" })
```