# How to pass List<string> to dropdown?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, viewbag

I have a list as follows:

```
List<string>WeekEnding={'10/07/2018','11/11/2018','01/21/2018'};
```

I want to pass it to the dropdown with name='10/07/2018' value='10/07/2018'

my dropdown is

```
  @Html.DropDownList("WeekEnding", null, new { Id = "WeekEnding", style = "width:50px;", @class = "form-control js-select", @size = "2" , required = "required" })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate @Html.DropDownList with a List<string> using MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333270/populate-html-dropdownlist-with-a-liststring-using-mvc), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688910/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlistfor-with-model-of-type-liststring & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772154/mvc-show-list-of-strings-in-dropdownlist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC - Show list of strings in DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772154/mvc-show-list-of-strings-in-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
@model List<string>
@Html.DropDownList(
    "WeekEnding", 
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),//you have to pass data as model. If you use another way you must change this line. 
        "Value",
        "Text"
    ),
    new { Id = "WeekEnding", style = "width:50px;", @class = "form-control js-select", @size = "2" , required = "required" }
)
```

Comment: NullException:value cannot be null

Comment: you have to pass data as model.

Comment: @SumitS. how do you pass data to view?

Comment: Thanx Its working now..previously i was trying to pass list through viewbag now its working with model

Answer (score 1):

I normally use `view models` to populate my drop down lists, even if it has basic values like dates (as in your code). Working on the way that you are wanting it, I would have done it like below.

Assuming you are working with the `Index action method` and `Index view`..

**Index action method**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<string> WeekEnding = new List<string>() { "10/07/2018", "11/11/2018", "01/21/2018" };

    return View(WeekEnding);
}
```

**Index view**

```
@model List<string>

@Html.DropDownList(
    "WeekEnding",
    new SelectList(
        Model.Select(x => new { Value = x, Text = x }),
        "Value",
        "Text"
    ),
    "-- Select --",
    new { @style = "width: 50px", @class = "form-control js-select", @size = "2", @required = "required" }
)
```

When viewing the `HTML` source after the page has been generated would look like this:

```
<select class="form-control js-select" id="WeekEnding" name="WeekEnding" required="required" size="2" style="width: 50px">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="10/07/2018">10/07/2018</option>
    <option value="11/11/2018">11/11/2018</option>
    <option value="01/21/2018">01/21/2018</option>
</select>
```

I hope this helps.